# error: #137: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c

I read all questions on this topic but no one of problems seems like mine. However, i'm getting an error: *expression must be a modifiable lvalue*. A part of C code where the errors founded is listed bellow.

```
 ws->fetch_next_state = &deg1_user_init;        
 ws->back_to_current  = &text_frame_print; 
 ws->_frame.text_buff[0] = deg_symbol_th; // error line
 ws->_frame.text_buff[1] = deg_symbol_te; //error line
 ws->_frame.object_no = 2;                                  
 ws->objects_counter = 0;`
```

Meaning of the upper code snipet is in passing the pointer of the constant memory area  to the routine which sends the characters to the peripheral device.

objects `deg_symbol_th` and `deg_symbol_te` are defined as

```
 char deg[2] = {0xF8, 0x00}; 
 const struct text_object deg_symbol_th = {6,3,2,45,240, deg};
 const struct text_object deg_symbol_te = {6,10,2,265,240, deg};
 const struct text_object deg_symb_svc =  {6,3,2,430,35, deg};
```

and `ws->_frame.text_buff[0]` is a part of the structure

```
struct frame
{
enum frame_sta frame_status;
enum frame_sta frame_status_diff;
const struct text_object *text_buff;
const struct box_object  *box_buff;
const struct area_object *area_buff;
uint8_t object_no;
};


struct wspace{
   struct netimer       period;
   struct nequeue   deferred;
   struct nevent *  deferred_queue_storage[EPA_EEPROM_QUEUE_SIZE];
   struct nepa *    producer;
   struct event_i2c_transfer        transfer;
   struct text_object   *Val_frame_buffer[15];
   struct frame        _frame;
   naction      (*back_to_current)(struct nsm * sm, const struct nevent * event); 
   naction      (*fetch_next_state)(struct nsm * sm, const struct nevent * event);           
   uint32_t     i2c_retry;
   uint8_t      i2c_buffer[35];
}ws;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Side note: Did you `malloc`-ate space for `text_buff[0]` somewhere in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member `text_buff` is a pointer-to-const-data, which means that even if you can change the value of the `text_buff` pointer itself, you cannot change the contents of the structure(s) that it is pointing to. In order to fix this, remove the `const` in the declaration `const struct text_object *text_buff`.

Comment: Ok, it's completely understandable, but the point is to have a pointer to const data. That data is memory objects which should be sent and there is no need to change them. The only which should be modified is the address of the object that is as assigning in the moment it need to be sent on bus and that's the purpose of the _const struct text_object *text_buff_.When remove the _const_ from the declaration compiler says  _error:  #513: a value of type const struct text_object *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct text_object *_.

Comment: If you want to have a pointer to const data, that's fine, but then you can't do what you are doing in the lines you point as "error line". Because, at those lines, you are modifying the data. The problem now is that you are initializing ``next_buff`` with a pointer to const data object, but that line is not included in your question. That pointer should also be a pointer to non-const if you are to assign it to ``next_buffer``.

Comment: I understand what you just said. It has sense. Thanks a  Atturri!